# Updating variable depending on specific condition in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a series of tuples in `C`, which is a log of activities by a user 1

```
scala> C.collect.foreach(println)
((1,A,1),1)
((1,B,2),1)
((1,C,4),2)
((1,D,7),3)
((1,E,15),8)
((1,F,16),1)
```

The third entry in the first tuple (1, 2, 4, 7 ,15, 16) is timestamp, and the second entry (1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 1) is the difference between consecutive timestamps.

I am trying to create a session whenever this user initiates an action either for the first time, or after a certain amount of time, `TIMEOUT`.

My plan is to first assign `ID`s to each tuple, and then map them into pairs. `ID`s will be the first timestamp in the session it belongs to.

For example, if `TIMEOUT = 2`, the example will be mapped to

```
(1, (1,"A",1))
(1, (1,"B",2))
(4, (1,"C",4)) //creation of a new session with ID 4
(7, (1,"D",7)) //creation of a new session with ID 7
(15, (1,"E",15)) //creation of a new session with ID 15
(15, (1,"F",16))
```

Then I will process data session by session.

However, I am having difficulty in this mapping.

I need to keep some sort of a global variable to keep track of the last timestamp within `TIMEOUT`, and update this variable when we are creating a new session, and make this the `ID`s of entries that follow.

Because this is `Spark`, I am using `Accumulator` `accum` like a global variable.

I am not sure how to set values of `accum` if the timestamp difference >= 2, and then use the new value as the `ID` of the new session. If timestamp difference < 2, the `ID` of the session remains the same.

My attempt so far was

```
val accum = sc.accumulator(0, "My Accumulator")
C.map(x => (x._2 match {
  case _ if (x._2 > -2) => accum.setValue(x._1._3); accum.value
  case _ => accum.value
}, x._1)).collect
```

and this fails.

I guess it's because `accum.setValue()` is a statement with a side effect, not a value, and this is not allowed in `scala`. Also, the mutation of object is frowned upon in `scala`. I know also the syntax is wrong. However, I cannot think of any other way to do this.

How can I achieve this mapping? Thank you.

Comment: pleeeeeeese don't use tuples for grouping data like this. Use case classes. Much easier to read, more typesafe, and easier to use.

Comment: How many records do you have? How many users? What is the average session length? How many entries per session do you expect? Do you need exact results or is it acceptable to some number of false positives? What is the total timeline (min-timestamp - max-timestamp)?

Comment: Hi, I will post more details after I figure them out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the side effect. Side effects are allowed in Scala where ever you want. They are just not encouraged in functional code. The problem is only that you need to put a function body into {} if you want it to have more then one statement in it. Also using a match only to have an if is pointless. I also assume you want the condition >= 2 not > -2, at least that would fit your example.

So this should work:

```
val accum = sc.accumulator(0, "My Accumulator")
C.map(x =>
  (if (x._2 >= 2) {
    accum.setValue(x._1._3)
    accum.value
  } else accum.value,
  x._1)
).collect
```

The only problem is the first id as you will have 0 in your id until you detect the first timeout. But your example does not really explain how you want to handle this edge case.

I would not use a side effect however to solve this. There is a method scanLeft on sequences that allows you to do a transformation while having access to the previous value:

```
val list = List(
  ((1,"A",1),1),
  ((1,"B",2),1),
  ((1,"C",4),2),
  ((1,"D",7),3),
  ((1,"E",15),8),
  ((1,"F",16),1))
list.tail.scanLeft((list.head._1._1, list.head._1)){
  case ((id, _), ((a, b, id2), delta)) =>
    if(delta < 2) (id, (a,b,id2))
    else (id2, (a,b,id2))
}
```

This also solves the problem with the first id as the first element is specified explicitly. This obviously assumes that there is at least one element in your sequence.

Comment: This won't work. It looks like `C` is `RDD` which is not `Iterable`. Moreover you cannot access accumulator value inside transformation.

Comment: I don't know spark. Looking at the documentation from RDD the first example will work syntactically, as RDD has a map method. But as RDD implements some distributed magic the side effect will not work. However this has nothing to do with Scala itsself. For the second example: this will work if you collect the data first. RDD does not have a scan. One could try to convert this into a fold, but I think this intrinsically sequential operation does not make much sense on a distributed data structure as RDD.

Comment: Well, it actually can be done in parallel but exact approach is highly dependent on a data distribution.

Comment: Yes it could. E.g. if you assume the block that get the same id are much smaller then the partitions of data you give to each process. Then each process can compute most of its part and only has to wait for the first id from an other process. But I don't see how this could be easily done using the RDD interface, and I won't look into it without know that this really is what the OP is asking.